Solutions of f(g(z))=F(z,f(z))
If $f,g$ are holomorphic inside the unit disk and $F=F(z,w)$ is a holomorphic function of two variables, can we solve for $f$ analyticaly in closed forms, including series, products or elementary functions, or even approximate solutions of the equation $$f(g(z))=F(z,f(z))$$ for $z$ in the unit disk?
The implicit function theorem implies the existance of such an $f$ under some mild assumptions, and I believe that even an iterative method would furnish a result after passing to the limit. A fixed point theorem would be nice as well. Even more radically, ideas from Galois theory, and field extentions might give something.
Do you have any suggestions? If it makes it easier, lets assume that $F$ is a polynomial in both $z$ and $w$, or even that $F(\lambda z, \lambda w)=\lambda^{p} F(z,w)$. In this case I could suggest expanding everything into power series and just comparing coefficients.
Is there any reference in the literature for such problems? Can we deduce some fundamental properties of $f$ even if an exact solution is not attainable?

So, is this research i.e., are you asking for a proof or counterexample whether or not it is true [because you are not sure either way]?

There is an obvious solution to this equation, for example, we can take $F(z,w)=z+w$, $g(z)=z^{2}$ and $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{2^{n}}$, and in fact my question stems from this example, in order to produce series that have the unit circle as a natural boundary. But, it seems interesting to me whatsoever, whether there are any anorthodox combinations of $f,g,F$ that produce a solution. I know of no other solution other than the one I mentioned, or at least I can not think of any at the moment... Thank you for your comment!

OK. I'm not really an expert on complex analysis or anything, just my comments/thoughts. I hope you get an  answer helpful to you
